# Rolling back EPEL 7

Tags: centos, mirror

I have a fresh installation of CentOS 6.5, and I accidentally added the EPEL 7 mirror, and performed a `yum update`. Is there an easy way to roll this back and add EPEL 6 instead?

---

## Update

I subsequently added EPEL 6 as well:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and now when I do

```
rpm -qa | grep epel
```

I get

```
epel-release-6-8.noarch
```

but when I try to install [`R`](http://cran.us.r-project.org/), I get

```
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libquadmath.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpng15.so.15(PNG15_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: R-java-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-headless
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.50()(64bit)
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The `R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64` leads me to believe that it is looking for the EL7 version of R, which has dependencies that are not resolved in the CentOS 6 mirrors.

Comment: hmmm maybe the command to uninstall the updates would work, also do you know for sure it updated the kernel?

Comment: @jgr208 I am not sure what that means. I installed EPEL 7 using `rpm -Uvh`, and then did a `yum update`. Please see the update for why I think that this is a problem for me.

Comment: `rpm -e` command

Comment: @jgr208 Yes, but EPEL 7 does not show up in the list when I do a `rpm -qa | grep epel`. Not sure why EL 7 version of R is being returned when I am trying `yum install R`.

Comment: `cat /etc/centos-release` and give output

Comment: also `uname -a`

Comment: @jgr208 CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: @jgr208 Linux <HOSTNAME> 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: so you are running 6.5 then not 7

Comment: @jgr208 Yes, which is why I am surprised that EL7 version of R is being processed for installation (R-core-3.1.1-3.el7.x86_64).

Comment: you might have to install from source

Comment: try `yum install R` as `root`

Comment: @jgr208 I am already `root`.

Comment: i just said root since you can't use yum without being root

Answer (score -1):

```
yum erase epel-release-6-8.noarch
yum install epel-release-6-8.noarch
```